# Java 8 iterate nested loop and fetch details

Tags: java, collections, java-8, stream

I have a model object which contains nested arrays and i want to retrieve some details within that model .How to collect property msg from subscriberCriteriaList into an array where subscriberCriteriaList.status is FAIL. I would expect java 8 solution for the same ? Below is the sample model objects and the corresponding json structure .

```
public class Data{
private List<subscriberList> subscriberCriteriaList;

}

public class subscriberList{

private String mdn;
private List<SubscriberCriteriaList> subscriberCriteriaList;

}

public class SubscriberCriteriaList{

private String status;
private String msg;

}
```

Sample json structure

```
   {
"subscriberList": [
  {       
    "mdn": "string",
    "subscriberCriteriaList": [
      {
        "status": "FAIL",
        "msg": "error message"
      }
    ]
  }
]
}
```

Comment: First, which JSON parser are you using? Please add your existing code.

Comment: @RealSkeptic : Expanded my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the top-level object has type `Data`, and appropriate getters are available in all the mentioned classes, it is possible to apply `flatMap` to the nested lists and filter by `status` value:

```java
String[] failureMessages = data.getSubscriberCriteriaList()
    .stream() // Stream<subscriberList>
    .flatMap(sl -> sl.getSubscriberCriteriaList().stream()) // Stream<SubscriberCriteriaList>
    .filter(scl -> "FAIL".equals(scl.getStatus()))
    .map(SubscriberCriteriaList::getMsg) // map to messages
    .distinct() // (optionally) remove duplicates if necessary
    .toArray(String[]::new);
```